# Molten Blade + Dead Man's Hand Interaction

Tags: hearthstone

Say I have a [Molten Blade](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Molten_Blade) in my hand, which turns into a random weapon and I also have a [Dead Man's Hand](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/62842-dead-mans-hand) which shuffles my hand into my deck.

If I allow my Molten Blade to transform into another weapon and then use Dead Man's Hand, does it stay a Molten Blade or does that card turn into whatever Molten Blade was at the time that I had cast Dead Man's Hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this out with 'Molten Blade', 'Shifter Zerus' and 'Shifting Scroll'. In all 3 cases you get what the card is currently turned into.
[image]

In this case Zerus turned into an Ancient of Lore and Molten Blade into Glaivezooka when I shuffled them in.

Comment: Wow, nice answer. You even went with all 3 changing cards! Well done!